# How to stick an image to the bottom of the visible part of a scrollable div

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

I have a drop-down menu that has a lot of content. If this dropdown is used on a mobile device, the user will be required to scroll down inside the `ul` (the `ul` has `overflow:scroll`) to reveal the rest of the content. This is somewhat unusual, so I want a downwards-pointing arrow on the bottom of the visible part of the `ul`.

I just cant seem to place it correctly.

I'm using javascript to set the height of the `ul` to never exceed the viewport height. I'm just scrolling inside the `ul` as intended, but it can be hard to that there's more menu-content in some cases.

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
  ...
  <img class="moreContent-arrow"> //Should be at the bottom of the visible part of the ul
</ul>
```

The `ul` has `position:absolute`. I've tried giving the arrow `position:absolute; bottom: 0;`, but that just puts it  in the correct position until you move the scrollbar.

I've been searching for an answer but I cant seem to find any searchwords that doesn't lead me to how to position a footer to the bottom of the page.

---

### EDIT 1:

Tried to use position:fixed on the image, but I'm using jquery's .slideToggle() on the opening and closing on the menu, meaning that the image which is fixed wont look good, as it pops in and out of existence without sliding into view with the rest of the content.

Comment: have you tried `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` ?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida, I tried that just now. Though it takes me closer to a wanted position, the menu opens with a jquery scroll, which makes the img pops in and out of existence without being visually affected by the scroll-animation. Which is not clean enough for me

Comment: have you tried placing a div outside the ul positioned to the bottom ? and also, you should try `height: 100vh` instead of calculating the height with javascript. `vh` stands for viewport height. so it will always be 100% of the viewport height. if you want it as a maximum only do `max-height: 100vh` then.

Comment: sorry, meant .slide(), not .scroll(), an viewport css doesn't look to be compatible with IE 8 and down, which i need

Comment: Could you post a jsBin test page? Or Fiddle? Or CodePen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying to realize what you want.

Try this:

```css
ul {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.list {
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}

img {  
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom:0px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

    <ul>
       <li>
           Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
           More Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          Even more Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          Last but not least, Stuff.
      </li>
      <li>
          Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          More Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          Even more Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          Last but not least, Stuff.
      </li>
      <li>
          Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          More Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          Even more Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
          Stuff
      </li>
      <li>
      Last but not least, Stuff.
      </li>
    </ul>
    <img class="moreContent-arrow">
</div>
```

The list has the `height` so change the calculation in your js to affect it.
Give the same height to the `ul`, and `overflow: auto`.

So, to explain what I did here, as you can notice what scrolls is the `ul`, that is inside the `.list`. The `img` has `position: absolute` relative to the `.list` not the `ul`. So when the `ul` scrolls, it doesn't affect the `img`.

Comment: Yes, your code does give me an intended menu behavior, but it doesn't solve it the way I wondered if was possible. I guess it cant be solved without a  .list "wrapper" of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

IF i get it right,

```
...
position:fixed;
...
```

Should be what you're looking for.

You can also use CSS to set the UL height instead of JS

Comment: I need to set it with JS because I need it to take the full height minus the height of the header. $(window).height() - 80;. Position fixed doesnt work because it looks bad with the jquery .slide(). i should have been clearer about my js use sorry

Answer (score 0):

I set up a JSFiddle. I gave the image a `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` and I made the container `position:relative`.

Edit: I just saw you said ul's position is absolute. It works with its position being absolute, too.

```css
ul {
    background-color:red;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

img {  
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      Stuff
      </li>
  <li>
      More Stuff
      </li>
  <li>
      Even more Stuff
      </li>
  <li>
      Stuff
      </li>
  <li>
      Last but not least, Stuff.
      </li>
  <img class="moreContent-arrow">
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if he has a scroll, the arrow will still appear in the middle of the div after scrolling.

Comment: Yes, your css works, but it is not a solultion to my problem. My UL  is a scrollable container, and the image needs to be glued to the bottom of the visible part of the ul, not just the bottom of the ul.